# Unable to connect mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

How do I pass an `action` to the `reducer` from my component?

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyApp extends Component {
    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text> {this.props.dataReducer.name} </Text>
          <Button
            onPress={this.props.setName('newName')}
            title="Click to change Name"
            color="blue"
          />
        </View> 
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    dataReducer: state.dataReducer
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    setName: (name) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_NAME",
        payload: name
      })
    }
  };
};


export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( MyApp )
```

The **dataReducer**:

```
const initialState = {
  name:'fromDataReducer',
  number: 545
}

export default function dataReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_NAME":
      return {
        ...state,
        name: action.payload
      }
    case "resetName":
      return {
        ...state,
        name: 'ResetFromDataReducer'
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

If I don't connect `mapDispatchToProps`, the app works fine. But when I `connect` it with `mapStateToProps`, the app is rendered as blank. Absolutely nothing. And I get the following alert after a few seconds:

[image]
[image]

My store in index.android.js is :

```
const store = createStore( rootReducer );
```

`rootReducer` is imported where I've combinedReducers. I don;t think `store` is an issue cause it's working without `mapDispatchToProps`.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing an argument to your **setName** function, you are firing it immediately.

Try using an arrow function in order to pass arguments:

```
<Button
    onPress={ () => this.props.setName('newName') }
    title="Click to change Name"
    color="blue"
/>
```

Comment: That worked! What a stupid mistake I made. So without the fat arrow the function tries to load even without clicking? But why was the screen blank?

Comment: Yes, applying parentheses cause a function to execute so wrapping it inside a function means it will only get run when the wrapping function is called. Happy this helped.

Comment: Firing the action causes the store to update, which causes the component to re-render. If the action is being fired immediately then this could cause this process to loop indefinitely.